# resque-status and resque-scheduler for delayed jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I used resque-scheduler for delay jobs in previous code:

```
Resque.enqueue_in(options[:delay].seconds, self, context)
```

Now I want to include resque-status to do the job but have no idea how they can work together. The latest resque-status source code supports scheduler, as in the source code:

https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status/blob/master/lib/resque/plugins/status.rb

```
# Wrapper API to forward a Resque::Job creation API call into a Resque::Plugins::Status call.
# This is needed to be used with resque scheduler
# http://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler
def scheduled(queue, klass, *args)
  self.enqueue_to(queue, self, *args)
end
```

end

But I'm not sure how to use it. Shall I just call SampleJob.scheduled(queue, myclass, :delay => delay) instead of SampleJob.create(options)?

======================================================================

Also, there is Support for resque-status (and other custom jobs):

https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler

Some Resque extensions like resque-status use custom job classes with a slightly different API signature. Resque-scheduler isn't trying to support all existing and future custom job classes, instead it supports a schedule flag so you can extend your custom class and make it support scheduled job.

Let's pretend we have a JobWithStatus class called FakeLeaderboard

```
class FakeLeaderboard < Resque::JobWithStatus
  def perform
    # do something and keep track of the status
  end
end
```

And then a schedule:

```
create_fake_leaderboards:
  cron: "30 6 * * 1"
  queue: scoring
  custom_job_class: FakeLeaderboard
  args:
  rails_env: demo
  description: "This job will auto-create leaderboards for our online demo and the status will update as the worker makes progress"
```

But it seems only for recurring jobs. I can find params of cron, but not delay. So how can I handle delayed jobs with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved by myself by implementing a module which provide a runner for "statused" jobs.

```
module Resque # :nodoc:

  # Module to include in your worker class to get resque-status
  # and resque-scheduler integration
  module ScheduledJobWithStatus

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      # Include status functionalities
      include Resque::Plugins::Status
    end

    # :nodoc:
    module ClassMethods

      # This method will use a custom worker class to enqueue jobs
      # with resque-scheduler plugin with status support
      def enqueue_at(timestamp, *args)
        class_name = self.to_s # store class name since plain class object are not "serializable"
        Resque.enqueue_at(timestamp, JobWithStatusRunner, class_name, *args)
      end

      # Identical to enqueue_at but takes number_of_seconds_from_now
      # instead of a timestamp.
      def enqueue_in(number_of_seconds_from_now, *args)
        enqueue_at(Time.now + number_of_seconds_from_now, *args)
      end

    end
  end

  # Wrapper worker for enqueuing
  class JobWithStatusRunner
    # default queue for scheduling jobs with status
    @queue = :delayed

    # Receive jobs from {Resque::ScheduledJobWithStatus} queue them in Resque
    # with support for status informations
    def self.perform(status_klass, *args)
      # Retrieve original worker class
      klass = status_klass.to_s.constantize
      # Check if supports status jobs
      unless klass.included_modules.include? Resque::Plugins::Status
        Rails.logger.warn("Class #{klass} doesn't support jobs with status")
        return false
      end
      Rails.logger.debug("Enqueing jobs #{klass} with arguments #{args}")
      klass.create(*args)
    rescue NameError
      Rails.logger.error("Unable to enqueue jobs for class #{status_klass} with args #{args}")
      false
    end
  end

end
```

In this way you can enqueue your jobs with this simple syntax:

```
# simple worker class
class SleepJob

  # This provides integrations with both resque-status and resque-scheduler
  include Resque::ScheduledJobWithStatus

  # Method triggered by resque
  def perform
    total = (options['length'] || 60).to_i
    1.upto(total) { |i| at(i, total, "At #{i} of #{total}"); sleep(1) }
  end

end

# run the job delayed
SleepJob.enqueue_in(5.minutes)
# or
SleepJob.enqueue_at(5.minutes.from_now)
```

Just drop the module in resque initializer or in `lib` folder. In the latter case remember to require it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`resque-scheduler` will call the `scheduled` method on the supplied class whenever it creates the job for your workers to consume. 
It also nicely passes both the queue name and class name as a string so you can create a class level method to handle scheduled job creation.

While Fabio's answer will solve the problem, it is a bit over-engineered to answer your specific question.
Assuming you have a `JobWithStatus` class that all of your `resque-status` workers inherit from, you need only add the `scheduled` method to it for it to work with the `resque-scheduler` as so:

```
class JobWithStatus
  include Resque::Plugins::Status

  def self.scheduled(queue, klass, *args)
    Resque.constantize(klass).create(*args)
  end
end
```

Comment: How do you indicate the date/time that you want Resque to execute the job?

Comment: @DonCote use the `enqueue_at` or `enqueue_in` methods of `resque-scheduler`.
They take your Job class as the second argument, and any data as the third.

For example:
`Resque.enqueue_at(5.minutes.from_now, JobWithStatus, { foo: 'bar' })`