# How to check the status of a job while using resque scheduler in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, jobs, resque-scheduler

I have some jobs running in the background to execute at some pre-mentioned time periods. I am using resque-scheduler gem to queue the jobs on Redis server. While I have their Job Ids, I want to know the status of that particular job. Is there any particular command or code which would help me to find the status of such jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [resque-status](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status) extension to achieve this. This is supported by [resque-scheduler](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler#support-for-resque-status-and-other-custom-jobs).

More related answers you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139879/resque-status-and-resque-scheduler-for-delayed-jobs).